# boto3 wait_until_running doesn't work as desired

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to write a script using boto3 to start an instance and wait until it is started. As per the documentation of wait_until_running, it should wait until the instance is fully started (I"m assuming checks should be OK) but unfortunately it only works for wait_until_stopped and incase of wait_until_running it just starts the instance and doesn't wait until it is completely started. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here or this is a bug of boto3.

Here is the code:

```
import boto3


ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name="ap-southeast-2")
ec2_id = 'i-xxxxxxxx'
instance = ec2.Instance(id=ec2_id)
print("starting instance " + ec2_id)
instance.start()
instance.wait_until_running()
print("instance started")
```

Comment: The waiter only waits until state is changed to `running` of the following: `pending`, `running`, `shutting-down`, `terminated`, `stopping`, `stopped`.

Comment: `wait_until_running()` should wait until the instance's state has changed to `running`. It will not wait until the operating system has fully booted, and all services have started, etc. which is what I assume you mean when you say "completely started".

Comment: Thaks @MarkB, I'm just thinking to put a sleep interval for a few seconds and check until port 22 is accessible (which makes sure that instance is finally up). Is this a good approach or is there any other better AWS way to get this done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [@Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b) [@Madhurya Gandi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4184525/madhurya-gandi) here is the solution that worked in my case:

```
import boto3,socket
retries = 10
retry_delay=10
retry_count = 0
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name="ap-southeast-2")
ec2_id = 'i-xxxxxxxx'
instance = ec2.Instance(id=ec2_id)
print("starting instance " + ec2_id)
instance.start()
instance.wait_until_running()
while retry_count <= retries:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((instance.public_ip_address,22))
    if result == 0:
        Print "Instance is UP & accessible on port 22, the IP address is:  ",instance.public_ip_address
        break
    else:
        print "instance is still down retrying . . . "
        time.sleep(retry_delay)
   except ClientError as e:
       print('Error', e)
```

Comment: Your formatting may have messed up the code example - "Print" with capital P is not going to work and your except ClientError statement wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this way wait until the instance status is 2/2 passed in the check tests:

[Boto3 Doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceStatusOk):
instance-status.reachability - Filters on instance status where the name is reachability (passed | failed | initializing | insufficient-data ).

```py
    import boto3

    client = boto3.client('ec2')

    waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_status_ok')
    waiter.wait(
        InstanceIds = ["instanceID"],
        Filters = [
            {
                "Name": "instance-status.reachability" ,
                "Values": [
                    "passed"
                ]
            }
        ]
    )


  [1]: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceStatusOk
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right way to do it is as follows:

```
   instance.wait_until_running(
            Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                    'Values': [
                        'running',
                    ]
                },
            ]
   )
```

tested and worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I've tried instance.wait_until_running(). It took time to update the instance to running state. As per amazon docs [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-ec2-launch.html), it says that the instances take a minimum of 60seconds to spin up. Here's a sample code that worked for me. Hope it helps!

;to create 5 instances

```
ec2.create_instances(ImageId='<ami-image-id>', MinCount=1, MaxCount=5)
time.sleep(60)
```

;print your instances

Comment: Thanks , that is what I did :) Looks like this is the only way to cop up with this.